# Update a customer field when update another customer field in account using trigger

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code

I want to write a trigger to update a "DueDate" field everytime "Balance" field is updated. not sure how to do it. currently I have:

public static void handleUpdate(Map oldMap, Account[] accounts)
{

```
    Map<Id,Account> newAccount=new Map<Id,Account>();
    for(Account acct: trigger.new)
    {   

    }
```

}

Not sure where I put the condition (if balance is update....)

Please Help, Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer: 
Make a variable called prevBalance=oldMap.get(acct.Id),
then the condition would be: if(acct.Balance != prevBalance) then update ~~~